# sql query execution order question for group by and select

Tags: mysql, sql

the table structure:

```
create table t_hr_ship (
shipment_id int,
shipper_id int,
date_time date,
pickup_state varchar(20),
dropoff_state varchar(20));
```

Here are some data in this table:

```
insert into t_hr_ship values
(1, 1, "2018-01-01", "WA", "OR"),
(2, 1, "2018-01-02", "WA", "OR"),
(3, 1, "2018-01-03", "WA", "OR"),
(4, 1, "2018-01-04", "WA", "OR"),
(5, 2, "2018-01-05", "WA", "OR"),
(6, 3, "2018-01-06", "WA", "OR"),
(7, 2, "2018-02-01", "OR", "WA"),
(8, 4, "2018-02-02", "OR", "WA"),
(9, 3, "2018-02-03", "WA", "CA"),
(10, 5, "2018-02-04", "CA", "OR"),
(11, 2, "2018-03-05", "WA", "TX"),
(12, 3, "2018-01-06", "OR", "CA");
```

the question is to get top 3 busiest routes in Jan and Feb. note that the route is same for "WA" to "OR" and "OR" to "WA" (the order of two end points don't matter as long as they are the same two end ports).
the solution is as below:

```
select case when s.pickup_state < s.dropoff_state then s.pickup_state else s.dropoff_state end as pickup, 
       case when s.pickup_state > s.dropoff_state then s.pickup_state else s.dropoff_state end as dropoff,
       count(s.shipment_id) as no_of_shipment
from t_hr_ship s
where month(s.date_time) in ("01","02")
group by pickup, dropoff
order by no_of_shipment desc
limit 3;
```

this does get what I expect. my question is: I read from online resource that the sql query execution order is `from -> where -> group -> having -> select -> order by -> limit", if this is true than this solution should not work because the`pickup`and`dropoff`defined in`select`can't be used in`group by`. am I missing anything?

Comment: The sequence should be     from -> where -> select -> group -> having ->   order by -> limit ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland the select  .. produce alias that are used  by group by  .. so must be execute before group  by ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland  .. the send result  to presentation layer .. is not the select clause  ..for what is know

Comment: @RaymondNijland  .. i think your commet could be useful  .. my opinion is for not remove

Comment: yes that comment which i made might be a bit to much oversimplified, also a reason why i removed it.. @scaisEdge

Comment: i think it is more or less this sequence path @scaisEdge feels a bit more accurate .. 1) from (permission check and read from tables) 2) where -> select (for group by/having alias usage and group by ANSI/ISO rules check) group by -> having (general filtering and rules checking) 3) select (alias usage) -> Order by 4) limit ... 5) select (to know which columns to send to the client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` to group by consistently:

```
select 
    least(pickup_state, dropoff_state) pickup,
    greatest(pickup_state, dropoff_state) dropoff,
    count(*) as no_of_shipment
from t_hr_ship s
where month(date_time) in (1, 2)
group by pickup, dropoff
order by no_of_shipment desc
limit 3;
```

Note that, unlike other RDBMS, MySQL allows the use of column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause (and as well in the `ORDER BY` clause, but this is common in most RDMS).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b993e50e43543dd48e4dd7bda9c7f8b0)**:

```
pickup | dropoff | no_of_shipment
:----- | :------ | -------------:
OR     | WA      |              8
CA     | OR      |              2
CA     | WA      |              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Execution order is NOT determined by the query.  SQL is not a procedural language, it is a *declarative* language.

The `SELECT` statement is describing the result set.  In fact, the ultimate execution path may have little resemblance to the actual query -- although MySQL is not as sophisticated as other databases.

What *is* specified is the order for interpreting the meaning of column aliases in the query.  That is what you are referring to.

Some databases, such as MySQL relax the standard and allow column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It works because you are using alias name. Yes to use the select columns in group by you have 3 options

1. case when s.pickup_state < s.dropoff_state then s.pickup_state else s.dropoff_state end
2. pickup
3. 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).